# Can't change branch or commit because of unmerged files. Can't merge or stash files because I'm in the wrong branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I went to push some files but got a merge error. I fixed it and went to merge again but got an error that I was no longer in the branch.

I went to switch back to the branch but couldn't; I got an error saying I still needed to merge my changes. Of course if I try to merge the changes I get an error saying I'm not in the right branch. Same if I try to stash.

Would anyone know how I can fix this? Or at least get back to my branch without needing to merge?

When I try to change Branches:

```
error: you need to resolve your current index first
filename.inc: needs merge
```

When I try to commit:

```
BUILD FAILED
You are not on the correct branch.
```

Git status:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#
#       modified: styles.inc

# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified: filename.inc
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? What client are you using?

Comment: Show your `git status` please.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Added above

Comment: @PhilipTzou added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `git diff filename.inc` to check if you did merge the file.
2. Use `git add filename.inc` to confirm this merge.
3. Use `git commit` to commit this merge.
4. You are all good now.